# Mysql: Select but only count if there is a row with two conditions

Tags: mysql

looked at all functions in w3schools.. just can't come up with which one to use.

Using mysql within metabase.

We have a table where every user events ist tracked:

```
id | name | userid | eventtime | deviceID
```

I'd like to have a line chart which shows for every day how many users opened the app on that for the first time and divide that number by the amount of users that at any time later signed up for the app.

When a user opens the app for the first time an event called platform_ready it looks something like this

```
**id01** | **platform_ready** | null | eventtime | deviceid
```

When he signs up then the event looks like this:

```
**id02** | **sign_up** | null | eventtime | deviceid
```

if he then performs any other event he has an userid!

```
**id03** | e.g. **select_content** | **userid** | eventtime | deviceid
```

if he instead of signing up closes the app and comes back again it's:

```
**id02** | **platform_ready** | null | eventtime (later) | deviceid
```

My challenge is now to find the the date where first opened the app, because if he is already signed up and opens the app platform_ready also gets an event:

```
**idxy** | **platform_ready** | **userid** | eventtime | deviceid
```

So two questions:

1. How do I get only the first opens and not any distinct device_id which performed 'platform_ready'?
2. How do I filter then if there was a 'sign_up' event later with that same deviceid?

Super happy for any help!

All the best,

Leon

```
+---------+----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|   ID    |      Name      |          Userid          |        Eventtime         |               Deviceid               |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 462,550 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:57 PM | 74E2C734-839C-4FF4-9D32-F31B8533717E |
| 462,547 | platform_ready | 5d9cece26a1a795a835ab880 | Februar 4, 2020, 5:57 PM | F0E18936-B28F-4604-B3DD-C60409EF8B9F |
| 462,538 | platform_ready | 5e1df19c8c8a95715b5289bf | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | 852296FB-4876-42B4-8A71-0AE53145362D |
| 462,534 | platform_ready | 5e33f6536be8d6062fa90a7a | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | 4CA49BB0-49F5-4E54-9FD7-8A615F65325F |
| 462,521 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | FB8C3AA3-3F00-4A80-961A-8DF862FA4755 |
| 462,502 | sign_up        | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | 5BC6377A-F2CA-4495-841F-52A15D7E53C0 |
| 462,499 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | 3EC6E5D0-893C-474B-A194-6DD191F7CEB7 |
| 462,496 | platform_ready | 5c2e08f60565b221487c3c95 | Februar 4, 2020, 5:51 PM | 53B96D09-8240-48F1-B81E-C4734DE78DB0 |
| 462,486 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:49 PM | 4871A36A-50E7-41C9-851C-0B89987AAA0C |
| 462,484 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:49 PM | b00f22c106a4b801                     |
| 462,477 | platform_ready | null                     | Februar 4, 2020, 5:49 PM | 229e12e0972fdeba                     |
| 462,469 | platform_ready | 5d9f8028159c395a76932897 | Februar 4, 2020, 5:49 PM | ced467944ac6db6a                     |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @Strawberry is not providing an MCRE a valid reason to vote-clode? I don't remember... I remember it may have been in the past.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos Absolutely. Yes.

Comment: what is vote-clode? Provided MCRE now :) sorry

Comment: Hi, I refer you again to the link attached to my previous comment.

Comment: 1. Is `**id01** | **platform_ready** | null | eventtime | deviceid` always the first entry that is inserted in the event list registry for a user/device?
2. You want a list of users/devices that only did the open app action?

Comment: @beachChicken Yes, that's always the first entry! 2. Yes, that would be awesome and once I have that list I could check whether they performed 'sign_up' later or not...

Comment: Is you provide a data sample that hold the table (CREATE TABLE) definition and the some sample data (some INSERT statement populating the table) then I will give it a try.